# Netsuite commands in browser console - getrecordtype

Tags: netsuite

I know there are scripting ways using searches to get the record type of a Netsuite record if I just have the internal ID, but is there a way to get the record type of that record using the browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a scripting way without using searches to get the record type of a NetSuite record, if you have the internal ID:

`nlapiGetRecordType({internalid})`

This can be run in the browser console on a NetSuite record page.

You can also get the internal ID of the current record using:

`nlapiGetRecordId()`

Putting them together, you can get the record type of any supported record in the browser of that record's page:

`nlapiGetRecordType(nlapiGetRecordId())`

Anyone familiar with SuiteScript will have noticed the above are the version 1.0 APIs.  In my opinion, these are the best for this usage as they are simple, one-line and quick, but for completeness here are the relevant 2.x APIs also.

To retrieve the internal ID in SS2.x you need to load the `N/currentRecord` module, `get()` the current record, and then the `id` is available as a property:

```
require(['N/currentRecord'], function(cr){
    console.log(cr.get().id);
});
```

To get the record type is very similar, as that is also available as a property once the current record object is loaded:

```
require(['N/currentRecord'], function(cr){
    console.log(cr.get().type);
});
```

All the provided examples should work in the browser console of a SuiteScript supported NetSuite record page.

Comment: I was attempting it with SS2.0, but in the console, as you said, it is harder, so your solution works much better for me.  I do note, however, that the record has to be in edit mode for this to work.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using the console, you could also refer to the "Field Explorer" Chrome extension that is free and available online to obtain field names (including 'record type') if you ever needed. I am always using this tool to find out names of fields.

NetSuite Field Explorer

[image]

Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-field-explorer/cekalaapeajnlhphgdpmngmollojdfnd?hl=en